# How to implement a search in a resolver using [nestjs/graphql]

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

**Problem**
Hello friends,

*I am trying to implement a resolve to do searches, but apparently the implementation is not correct. The `resolver search` should receive a query as a parameter, then using the `useSearch` function will return the data. But it shows me an error, which you can see at the bottom.*

*If someone can help me solve the problem I will appreciate it.*

**Hooks**

```js
export async function useSearch(query: String){
  const data = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/Search/${query}`)
    .then(res =>{
      return res.data.search;
    }).catch(err =>{
      console.log(err)
    });
  return data;
};
```

**Resolvers**

```js
import { Query , Resolver, Args}  from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { 
  useLatestAnime,
  useSearch
 } from './hooks/index';


@Resolver()
export class AnimesResolver{
  latestAnime = useLatestAnime()
    .then(res =>{
      return res;
    });

  search = (query: String) =>{
    const data = useSearch(query)
      .then(res =>{
        return res;
      });
    return data;
  }


  @Query('latestAnime')
  getLatestAnime(){
    const data = this.latestAnime.then(res =>{
      return res;
    })
    return data;
  }

  @Query('search')
  getSearch(@Args('query') query: String){
    const res = this.search(query)
      .then(res =>{
        return res;
      })
    return res;
  }
}
```

**Error**

```sh
(node:11940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Query.search defined in resolvers, but not in schema
(node:11940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not 
handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:11940) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

I had forgotten to define it in the Query

```
type Query{
  latestAnime: [Animes]
  search(query: String): [Animes]
}
```